# How could I setup a permanent connection to github from server with SSH key?

Tags: github, ssh-keys

I followed the guide from https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/ to generate a ssh key used to connect to github from my server.

The problem is if I close the shell and login the server again, I have to repeat below steps to reconnect to github, otherwise the accessing will be denied:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

How can I setup a permanent connection with github?

Comment: This isn't about a "permanent connection with GitHub", but rather a way to have your `ssh-agent` run persistently. This will depend on your operating system. Please tell us what OS you are using, and which version.

Comment: @Chris thanks. I am using CentOS 6.7

Comment: Using a graphical environment like Gnome or KDE, or command-line only?

Comment: Do you have a passphrase on your SSH key (i.e. when you run `ssh-add` do you have to type a passphrase in)?

Comment: @Chris no. I didn't set pass

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea why I didn't get the notification of your answer. I will try it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are logging on to the command-line (presumably using SSH) all applications that you run, including `ssh-agent`, stop when you log out.

In my opinion your best bet is to have your CentOS machine start `ssh-agent` for you each time you log in, then manually use `ssh-add` to add your key. This can be done by modifying your shell's login script. If you are using bash, this file is called `~/.bash_profile`. If you are using another shell, refer to its documentation and choose an appropriate file.

Edit one of these files and add `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` at the end.

Now, each time you log in `ssh-agent` should automatically start, and you can optionally run `ssh-add` (since you are using a file that `ssh-add` looks for by default you don't need to pass the file to the command) to add your key, then do Git stuff.

It sounds like you want to automate the adding of the key as well. This isn't something that I would choose to do since I like adding keys to be explicit, but because you don't have a passphrase on your SSH key you should be able to add `ssh-add` to the same file we modified above (after we start the agent, of course) and have your key added automatically.

Comment: This works for shell. But I just found that after changing the `.bashrc` file, the FTP didn't work. I used FileZilla, it shows 'connected to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', but the window of files is blank.

Comment: @BrickYang, SSH keys have nothing to do with FTP. Perhaps you mean [SFTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol)? In any case, [you specified in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33710880/how-could-i-setup-a-permanent-connection-to-github-from-server-with-ssh-key/33721078?noredirect=1#comment55194098_33710880) that you are using "CLI only". FileZilla is a graphical program, and is very likely to require different treatment. Also, I doubt that you are running it on your CLI-only server. Please submit your FileZilla question separately.

Comment: Thanks. I posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34428134/after-setting-bashrc-the-filezilla-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Chris
I did the following and it worked:-
Step1:- .bash_profile
Step2:- [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUVV0.png)

Step3:-source .bash_profile

Step4:- [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oN1T.png)