# After setting ~/.bashrc the FileZilla doesn't work

Tags: centos, sftp, ssh-keys, filezilla

To auto add ssh key I edited the `~/.bashrc` file and added `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` and `ssh-add` at the end. It works well.

After doing this, I cannot visit the server via SFTP with FileZilla.

How can I fix this with keep auto running `ssh-add`?

My server OS is CentOS 6.7. I also access the server via shell.

Comment: In your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33710880/how-could-i-setup-a-permanent-connection-to-github-from-server-with-ssh-key) you were trying to SSH _from_ a CentOS server _to_ GitHub. Now it sounds like you are trying to connect _to_ your CentOS server, from some other machine running FileZilla. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. I run git on CentOS server to pull project from GitHub and access the server from local Mac via shell and FileZilla.

Comment: The changes you made to SSH from your server to GitHub have nothing to do with allowing incoming SSH to your server. The two are entirely separate. It looks like this question will shortly be closed for being off-topic. You may have better luck on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/). You should ask about setting up an SSH _server_ on CentOS.

Comment: My question is about access server with FileZilla. I am sure edting the .bashrc file caused the sftp doesn't work, how can I use auto `ssh-add` and FileZilla meanwhile, this is my question. Why it's off-topic? Because I mentioned local shell? I don't think so.

Comment: You think the changes you made to `~/.bashrc` broke your existing SFTP access using FileZilla? That would surprise me. Does FileZilla keep a log of what went wrong when trying to connect?

Comment: The log just shows "Connected to 101.200.xxx.xxx", but the server window is blank which should show the files and the local window shows "didn't connect to any server"(translation). I think it is `~/.bashrc` because if I remove the `ssh-add` sentence from `~/.bashrc` the FileZilla works fine, and add the sentence, the problem appears. This is reproducible. I am not sure if `~/.bashrc` broke FileZilla directly, I just tried my best to describe the the phenomenon

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98809/discussion-between-chris-and-brick-yang).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The guy who answered [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33710880/how-could-i-setup-a-permanent-connection-to-github-from-server-with-ssh-key)¹ got something wrong: `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` should only be executed for login shells (e.g. when you are logging in over regular SSH to run commands on the server's command-line).

Other tools, like FileZilla, may log in with non-interactive shells and these tools don't need or want the SSH Agent to be running.

`~/.bashrc` applies to *both* types of shells, so it is not the right place to start `ssh-agent`. `~/.bash_profile` is a better choice since it only applies to login shells. Move the `ssh-agent` command there and everything should work again.

¹I'm that guy. Sorry for steering you wrong! I'll update that answer too.